# Combining 2 arrays into 1

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array like this:

```
$array = Array( 
    array(
        [a] => something, 
        [b] => something
    )
)
```

Then I have another array the same, if I want to combine them to create an array like this:

```
Array( 
    [0] => Array( 
        [a] => something, 
        [b] => something
    )
    [1] => Array( 
        [a] => something, 
        [b] => something
    )
)
```

How can I achieve that? I thought using array_merge would help but that gives me:

```
Array( 
    [0] => Array( 
        [a] => something, 
        [b] => something
    )
    [1] => something, 
    [2] => something
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just tried this and it worked:

```
$new_array = array(
    $array_one,
    $array_two,
);
```

Try it yourself [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/312e23659370e3fb6881bd545893aba6e1c8a3e1).

Comment: What is the array(2)?

Comment: `Array (2)` is `$new_array`. `(2)` is just the number of items it has inside.